# ASP.NET Core app with windows authentication giving wrong user identity

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have an SPA ASP.NET Core application using Angular for frontend, running in IIS (as out-of-process) and using Windows authentication. There is an weird behavior when multiple users are logged on, only one of them, at a moment, will have in backend (in the controller) the **User.Identity** of another one that is logged on and all UI calls (made from angular) are done with this wrong user. If the page is refreshed, the issue dissapears. I was unable to find the steps that reproduce it, it seems to appear randomly. The controller extends *ControllerBase* and acceses user thru *User* propery of it, no custom code is used for authentication or accessing logged user.
IIS configuration scheme was configured thru Startup.ConfigureServices(): `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`
Authentication is included in HTTP request pipeline, in Startup.Configure():
`app.UseAuthentication();`

Only Windows authentication is enabled in IIS, the rest are disabled.
Not sure if relevant, but there is no method marked as async in the controllers.
I tried with both **ControllerBase.User** and **HttpContext.User**.
The application uses *.NET Core 2.2* and *Angular 6*, running on *Windows Server 2016* and *IIS 10.0.14393*.